# Como puedo asignar un Objeto como "unique" con mongoose?

Tags: nodejs, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Buen dia.
Estoy tratando de hacer que un objeto sea unico, con mongoose hacer esto con un string simplemente es asignarle un "unique: true", pero no funciona con objetos.
¿Es posible hacerlo con objetos?

Estoy usando node js y TypeScript

El schema lo definí de la siguiente manera, pero no funciono.

```
const configContabilidasSchema = new Schema<contabilidad>(
  {
    ip: {
      ip_local:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        
      },
      cod:{
        type: String,
      },
      type: Object,
      index: true,
      unique: true
    },
    modulos: {
      type: Array
    },
  },
  { versionKey: false }
  );
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo, quieres que en el campo ip la combinación de sus entradas (ip_local, cod) no se repitan, para hacerlo "único".

Puedes usar Unique Indexes en MongoDB. ‎Un índice único garantiza que los campos indexados no almacenen valores duplicados; es decir, impone la unicidad para los campos indexados. De forma predeterminada, MongoDB crea un índice único en el campo ‎‎_id‎‎ durante la creación de una colección.‎

Si vamos a [Unique Indexes (docs)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-unique/), vemos que para un ‎índice único en un solo campo sería:

```
db.members.createIndex( { "user_id": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Para índice compuesto único‎:

```
db.members.createIndex( { groupNumber: 1, lastname: 1, firstname: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Si utiliza la restricción única en un ‎‎índice compuesto‎‎, MongoDB aplicará la unicidad en la ‎‎combinación‎‎ de los valores de clave de índice.‎

También, se muestra otro ejemplo de una colección con un documento similar al suyo:

```
{ _id: 1, a: [ { loc: "A", qty: 5 }, { qty: 10 } ] }
```

Para crear un índice ‎‎multiclave‎‎ compuesto único en‎ el objeto del array, utilice la notación punto y encerrando entre comillas para poder acceder a las propiedades:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { "a.loc": 1, "a.qty": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Ahora bien, le voy a dejar algunas pruebas usando su estructura en MongoDB

```
test> 
>>> db.contabilidad.insertone( { ip: {ip_local: '1111.2222.3333.4444', cod: '1' }, modulos: ['A'] })
{
  acknowledged: true,
  insertedId: ObjectId("62452984cc591ab6bee98540")
}
test> 
>>> db.contabilidad.find().pretty()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62452984cc591ab6bee98540"),
    ip: { ip_local: '1111.2222.3333.4444', cod: '1' },
    modulos: [ 'A' ]
  }
]
test> 
>>> db.contabilidad.createIndex( { 'ip.ip_local': 1, 'ip.cod': 1 }, { unique: true } )
ip.ip_local_1_ip.cod_1 
test> 
>>> db.contabilidad.insertOne( { ip: {ip_local: '1111.2222.3333.5555', cod: '2' }, modulos: ['B'] })
{
  acknowledged: true, 
  insertedId: ObjectId("62452ab3cc591ab6bee98541")
}
test>
>>> db.contabilidad.find().pretty()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId( "62452984cc591ab6bee98540"), 
    ip: { ip_local: '1111.2222.3333.4444', cod: '1' }, 
    modulos: [ 'A' ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("62452ab3cc591ab6bee98541"), 
    ip: { ip_local: '1111.2222.3333.5555', cod: '2' }, 
    modulos: [ 'B' ]
  }
]
test> 
>>> db.contabilidad.insertone { ip: {ip_local: '1111.2222.3333.4444', cod: '1' }, modulos: ['A'] }) 
Uncaught 
MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.contabilidad index: ip.ip_local_1_ip.cod_1 dup key: { ip.ip_local: "1111.2222.3333.4444", ip.cod: "1"} 
test> 
>>> db.contabilidad.insertone { ip: {ip_local: '1111.2222.3333.4444', cod: '2' }, modulos: ['A'] })
{
  acknowledged: true, 
  insertedId: ObjectId("62452b20cc591ab6bee98543")
}
test> 
>>> db.contabilidad.find().pretty()
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId( "62452984cc591ab6bee98540"), 
    ip: { ip_local: '1111.2222.3333.4444', cod: '1' }, 
    modulos: [ 'A']
  },
  {
    _id: objectId("62452ab3cc591ab6bee98541"), 
    ip: { ip_local: '1111.2222.3333.5555', cod: '2' }, 
    modulos: [ 'B' ]
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId( "62452b20cc591ab6bee98543"), 
    ip: { ip_local: '1111.2222.3333.4444', cod: '2' }, 
    modulos: [ 'A' ]
  },
]
test> 
>>>
```

En Mongoose he utilizado el método `schema.index()` para crear índices

```
...
const configContabilidasSchema = new Schema<contabilidad>( { ... } );
configContabilidasSchema.index({ 'ip.ip_local': 1, 'ip.cod': 1 }, { unique: true });
...
```

Comment: Me funciono! Muchas gracias, era justo lo que necesitaba!